# Missing keyword ora -00905

Tags: sql

I am getting the error indicated in the question title when I execute the following query:

```
select mantas_stg.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.*,
CASE WHEN  MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_CURR != 'USD' THEN 
CASE WHEN  MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_CURR != 'USD' AND MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_LOCAL_CURR != 'USD'  THEN 
MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT = MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT * 100
END
END 
from mantas_stg.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG;
```

Can anyone tell me why the above query is failing at

```
MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT = MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT * 100
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is very hard to read.

Comment: You can't have an assignment in the select list like that.

Answer (score 0):

The line below in your nested `case` is probably the issue:

`THEN MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT = MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT * 100`

You're trying to assign a value to `MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT` in a `select` statement which isn't allowed

If your goal is to update the value in that column of a particular record you should be using an `update` statement.

Comment: select mantas_stg.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.*,
CASE WHEN  MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_CURR != 'USD' THEN 
CASE WHEN  MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_CURR != 'USD' AND MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_LOCAL_CURR != 'USD'  THEN 
MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT = 'hello'
END
END 
from mantas_stg.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG;

this worked fine, while i was trying to test it

Comment: Really? Could be your query never made it to that case block so it didn't blow up. What did the result-set of that query look like? I'm having a hard time believing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't assign values in a `case` expression.  I think you want something like this:

```
select s.*,
       (CASE WHEN s.FUNDS_ORIG_CURR <> 'USD' AND s.FUNDS_LOCAL_CURR <> 'USD'
             THEN s.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT * 100
             ELSE s.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT
        END) as new_funds_orig_amt
from mantas_stg.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG s;
```

Indentation and table aliases sure make the query easier to read.